# Unused options when passing key-value-pairs to class

Tags: pgfkeys, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to pass a key-value-pair to a class using pgfopts. The file `testclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2016/12/04 A Test Class]

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

\pgfkeys{testclass/testkey/.initial=testkeyinitial}
\pgfkeys{testclass/.is family}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/testclass}

\pgfkeys{testclass, testkey/.get=\optiontest}
```

and `testfile.tex` to test the class:

```
\documentclass[testkey=works]{testclass}

\begin{document}
Test: \optiontest
\end{document}
```

However the output is just the initial value `testkeyinital` and there is a warning emitted during compilation:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [testkey=works].
```

What am I missing? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist, note that `/testclass/` is not the same as `testclass/`. So you at least need

```
\pgfkeys{%
  /testclass/testkey/.initial=testkeyinitial,
  /testclass/.is family,
}
```

Second, I would recommend defining and handling all options before `\LoadClass`. This is because in a real parasitic class, you generally want to pass all unknown options to the base class. `pgfopts` doesn't seem to care two hoots about this, which surprised me, both other methods of handling options do care and it is probably good housekeeping to stick to the usual pattern unless there is compelling reason to do otherwise. (That is, it makes me nervous!)

With the path suitably corrected, the code you are using would work if you were dealing with package options, but does not work when used for class options.

Using `.store in` instead resolves the problem.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}[2016/12/04 A Test Class]

\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

\pgfkeys{%
  /testclass/.is family,
  /testclass,
  testkey/.store in=\optiontest,
  testkey=testkeyinitial,
}

\ProcessOptions

\ProcessPgfOptions{/testclass}

\LoadClass{article}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[testkey=works]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Test: \optiontest

\end{document}
```

[image: working code: alternative method]

## Why does the original method not work?

I am not certain about the following. However, I think that what happens is that `pgfopts` relies on testing for `<key path>/<key name>/.@cmd` in the case of class options (see p. 4 of the manual). It does this so that it can ignore options which are not relevant and which should only be processed by the class itself in the normal way. Otherwise, `12pt` say or `a4paper` would be passed to `pgfkeys` for processing.

However, `.initial` doesn't define a key as such. Rather it defines a key handler with the relevant name. Hence, there is no `<key path>/<key name>/.@cmd` and the option is assumed to be one which should be passed to the class rather than processed by `pgfopts`.

Note that even when the key is processed correctly because it is a regular key rather than a handler, the class will still complain that the option is unknown. `pgfopts` shares this feature with similar key-handling packages such as `l3keys2e` which process the options correctly but do not prevent LaTeX warning that they are unknown and unprocessed. As far as LaTeX is concerned, it appears that here is processing and then there is being-seen-to-be-processing ....